# Как несколько раз добавить информацию из textbox'а в listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

у меня есть код:

```
private void SendButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (MessageBox.Text != "")
        {
            string msg = MessageBox.Text;
            Messages_List.Items.Add(msg);
            MessageBox.Clear();
        }

    }

        <Border Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox x:Name="Messages_List">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="15" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Alignment}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                    <TextBlock Margin ="10 10 10 10" FontSize="15" x:Name="View_Message" Text="{Binding ElementName=MessageBox, Path=Text}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Border>
```

При нажатии кнопки информация из textbox'а передаётся в listbox, но при повторном вводе информации в textbox, уже отправленное сообщение в listbox тоже изменяется, как этого избежать?

Comment: `new String(MessageBox.Text.ToCharArray())` - это вообще зачем? преобразуете строку в массив и потом обратно создаете из него строку. По поводу самого вопроса - покажите код метода целиком. И желательно xaml разметку. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за такую быструю реакцию) Вот изменения)

Comment: `Text="{Binding}"` - вот так. Не надо никаких `ElementName` там. И переименуйте текстбокс, у вас конфлик с названием стандартного класса `MessageBox`.